# Error appeared when running my App on iPhone6 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

my app is running well on simulator 
but when tried to run it on iPhone6 device the following two errors turned up :

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CustomView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TransparentView.o

and

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

the CustomView is header file included in staticLibrary 
the code which I have is :

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>



@interface CustomView : UIView<CLLocationManagerDelegate>



@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableDictionary* reducedlatLongDict;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *reducednamesRequiredToLoad;

-(NSMutableArray*)sendTheDataToMainClass:(NSDictionary*)sendDictyionary :(NSString*)filterString1;
-(NSMutableArray*)gettingTheHeading:(CLHeading*)newHeading;
-(NSMutableArray*)getTheLocationUpdate:(CLLocation*)newLocation :(CLLocation*)fromLocation;

@end
```

Comment: What is CustomView? Where is it defined?

Comment: the code is running well on simulator , but when trying to run it on iPhone-6  and iPhone-5 the same error appeared

Comment: show us the code for custom view>

Comment: CustomView which I had between my hand is header file only which is included within staticLibrary

Comment: here is the code I have:

Comment: your library is missing `x64` bit architecture

Comment: I'd probably say that the library hasn't been included in the build resources  when building to device.

Comment: From where you got your static lib?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I am inclined to your point of view
I got the library from the company whom I work for , it was developed by ex-developer who used to work to for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static library is missing `arm64` architecture.

You can check the architecture supported by your lib by the following command in terminal

```
lipo --info /path/to/yourLib.a
```

---

If it's your own lib the you might have to change to architecture and rebuild it again.

[image]

---

#### And if you don't own the lib, then you can get the updated lib from the original source.

Comment: I tried  lipo -info and this is the result 
Architectures in the fat file: /my_staticLibrary_Path are: armv7 i386 x86_64

Comment: This clearly means that `arm64` is missing and thus it won't work on iphone5s, iphone6 and iphone6+. Although it includes `x86_64` and will work for every simulator.